# Substitute xml tag value using awk

Tags: xml, substitution

Script for extracting tag value using awk

**XML**

```
2022-02-08 [this is the actual log file] BLAH - This is how my xml log file is <sometag id="00000-00000"<name>sam</name><phone>98762123</phone><DOB>12-09-77</DOB><bankaccount>4563728495847</bankaccount></sometag>
2022-02-09 [this is the actual log file] BLAH - This is how my xml log file is <sometag id="00000-00000"<name>sam</name><phone>123456789</phone><DOB>12-09-77</DOB><bankaccount>4563728495847</bankaccount></sometag>
2022-02-08 [this is the actual log file] BLAH
2022-02-08 [this is the actual log file] BLAH
2022-02-08 [this is the actual log file] BLAH
```

**output file**

```
2022-02-08 [this is the actual log file] BLAH - This is how my xml log file is <sometag id="00000-00000"<name>s**</name><phone>9**6**2*</phone><DOB>**-**-**</DOB><bankaccount>4**37**4**8**</bankaccount></sometag>
2022-02-09 [this is the actual log file] BLAH - This is how my xml log file is <sometag id="00000-00000"<name>s**</name><phone>9**6**2*</phone><DOB>12-09-77</DOB><bankaccount>4**37**4**8**</bankaccount></sometag>
2022-02-08 [this is the actual log file] BLAH
2022-02-08 [this is the actual log file] BLAH
2022-02-08 [this is the actual log file] BLAH
```

PS: using awk to parse xml is not the best option Im aware, but I have no options here.

Comment: [edit] your question to either explain why DOB and bankaccount have been modified in your expected output when they do not have a Yes flag in your lookup file or fix whichever of your input or expected output is wrong.

Comment: Why is awk your only option? Why can't you use XML aware tools to do the job?

Comment: @MadsHansen looks like the XML is embedded in some non-XML plain text in each line that also has to be reproduced in the output. Is there an XML-aware tool that can handle that input format? I suppose we could use awk to isolate the XML parts from the rest and then spawn a sub-process to call an XML-aware tool for the XML part but then we're already using awk to identify what is/isn't XML and that'd introduce some additional complexity in ensuring the XML-aware tool generates all output as a single line, reading it back into awk to put back into the line, etc. and would be very slow.

Comment: Also, can any XML-aware tool do the kind of masking the OP requires where it'd have to check for each tag being present in some other file and then, if present, change the value to replace every 2nd and 3rd char (repeated) in the value with `*`? I really don't know but my instinct on this one, especially given such simple, rigid XML input, is that it does make sense to just do everything in 1 call to awk.

Comment: Hi Felicity, I rejected your edit to my answer, because you were replacing it with a very different `gawk` solution. I understand that this solution is shorter and may have worked better for you. But my solution may be useful to someone who wants a POSIX (portable) awk solution to a similar problem. If the question hadn't been closed, I would recommend instead to post your edit as an answer, and accept it (you can accept your own answer after 2 days).

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk for the 3rg arg to match() and gensub():

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="," }
NR==FNR {
    if ( $2 == "Yes" ) {
        mask[$1]
    }
    next
}
match($0,"(.*<sometag[^<>]+)(.*)(</sometag>.*)",rec) {
    bef = rec[1]
    xml = rec[2]
    aft = rec[3]

    $0 = bef
    while ( match(xml,"(<([^>]+)>)([^<]*)(<[^>]+>)",tagVals) ) {
        tag = tagVals[2]
        if ( tag in mask ) {
            val = tagVals[3]
            masked = gensub(/(.)../,"\\1**","g",val"  ")
            tagVals[3] = substr(masked,1,length(val))
        }
        $0 = $0 tagVals[1] tagVals[3] tagVals[4]
        xml = substr(xml,tagVals[0,"length"])
    }
    $0 = $0 aft
}
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk lookup.txt file
2022-02-08 [this is the actual log file] BLAH - This is how my xml log file is <sometag id="00000-00000"<name>s**</name><phone>9**6**2*</phone><DOB>12-09-77</DOB><bankaccount>4563728495847</bankaccount></sometag>
2022-02-09 [this is the actual log file] BLAH - This is how my xml log file is <sometag id="00000-00000"<name>s**</name><phone>1**4**7**</phone><DOB>12-09-77</DOB><bankaccount>4563728495847</bankaccount></sometag>
2022-02-08 [this is the actual log file] BLAH
2022-02-08 [this is the actual log file] BLAH
2022-02-08 [this is the actual log file] BLAH
```

The above is assuming your posted expected output is wrong and you don't really expect the DOB or bankaccount values to change.

Answer (score 0):

POSIX awk:

```
$ cat mask-list
name         1
phone        10010010
DOB          00100100
bankaccount  1001100100100

$ cat mask.sh
awk '
function mask(str, str_masked) {
    for (j=1; j<=length(str); j++) {
        if (substr(masks[i], j, 1)==1) {
            c = substr(str, j, 1)
        } else {
            c = "*"
        }

        str_masked = str_masked c
    }

    return str_masked
}

FNR == NR {
    tags[NR-1] = $1
    masks[NR-1] = $2
}

FNR != NR {
    line = $0

    for (i in tags) {
        regex = "<"tags[i]">[^<]+</"tags[i]">"
        masked_line = ""
        l = length(tags[i])

        while (match(line, regex) > 0) {

            # extract tag value and mask it
            fulltag = substr(line, RSTART, RLENGTH)
            tagval = substr(fulltag, l+3, RLENGTH-l-l-5)
            fulltag_masked = "<"tags[i]">" mask(tagval) "</"tags[i]">"

            # append the line portion before tag, and the masked tag
            masked_line = masked_line substr(line, 1, RSTART-1) fulltag_masked

            # truncate line start to end of matched tag, for next match
            line = substr(line, RSTART + RLENGTH)
        }

        line = masked_line line
    }

    print line
}' "$@"
```

Example:

```
$ sh mask.sh mask-list log-file
2022-02-08 [this is the actual log file] BLAH - This is how my xml log file is <sometag id="00000-00000"<name>s**</name><phone>9**6**2*</phone><DOB>**-**-**</DOB><bankaccount>4**37**4**8**</bankaccount></sometag>
2022-02-09 [this is the actual log file] BLAH - This is how my xml log file is <sometag id="00000-00000"<name>s**</name><phone>1**4**7**</phone><DOB>**-**-**</DOB><bankaccount>4**37**4**8**</bankaccount></sometag>
2022-02-08 [this is the actual log file] BLAH
2022-02-08 [this is the actual log file] BLAH
2022-02-08 [this is the actual log file] BLAH
```

Explanation:

- Read the mask file for tags to mask, and their mask pattern.
- For the log file, use `match()` and `substr()` to get each relevant `<tag>val</tag>` sub-string in a variable, and `substr()` again to get `val`, so it can be passed to a function that masks it, based on the pattern for the current tag.
- Re-assemble and repeat, for each tag.
- The mask list includes a corresponding mask pattern. `1` means show, any other character (or none, see `name`) means hide. You can add more entries.
- In the `mask()` function, there is an unused parameter `str_masked`, to keep that variable's scope local.
- `substr()` is used to compare the string and the mask pattern one character at a time.